# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del navbar y del footer, por cada opción del navbar?

Tags: html, python, django

Lo que me gustaría saber específicamente es que cuando se seleccione cada una de las opciones del `navbar` me cambie el color del fondo, tanto del `navbar` como del `footer`, pero que por cada opción del `navbar` me de un color diferente.

Todo esto con el fin de aplicarlo a una plantilla de Django.

Comment: Pone un ejemplo. Y modifica tus etiquetas. Lo podes resolver con CSS y JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo, espero te sirva

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("ul").css("background-color", "#309bff");
    $("footer").css("background-color", "#309bff");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff7683;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
footer{
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff7683;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Navbar</h2>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

<footer>

esto es el footer

</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor evita responder preguntas mal formuladas. Visita: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer